# How to Deploy and Restart an Spring Boot application on EC2 Linux with variable jar name

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

I have one apllication on Spring boot that I create a CI/CD using AWS CodePipeline, CodeBuild e CodeDeploy to deploy the jar file in EC2 Linux instance. I've had to config one script on EC2 using systemd Service to start, stop, and restart any release of that application, but my Jar file name have a number o version of this app, EX: myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and the systemd Service was configured to start the application with that name.

The problem is when I have to deploy a new release of this app with another name in the Jar file Ex: myapp-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, my script won't be able to start, restart and stop that application because the name change. How can I solve that problem without rewrite the systemd Service manually ?

Comment: Can you simply normalize file name when deploying to the instance (cp myapp-*-SNAPSHOT.jar mapp.jar) - and this way you would have stable script?